# How to get rid of these many camera devices?

Tags: drivers, webcam, camera, obs-studio

I have installed many camera devices, and I can’t seem to remove them nor uninstall the driver. What can I do?

I searched through Device Manager, but I cannot find the camera device name. Here's the several screenshots of what I am seeing:

**Output from `https://webcamtests.com/`**:

[image: https://webcamtests.com/]

**Google Meet settings**:

[image: Google meet settings]

**Zoom settings**:

[image: Zoom settings]

Apparently now I only using USB Video ([You can read here](https://www.theverge.com/21346571/cheap-cam-link-capture-card-streamer-clone-review-test-price)) to capture my DSLR through HDMI and output it to OBS and using OBS virtual cam to register as a webcam to other software that I use. So I would like to remove all except USB Video and OBS-Camera.

Comment: Which devices do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: All, except USB Video and OBS-Studio

Comment: So have you tried to uninstall DroidCam and the Nikon utility software?

Comment: I have (using revo uninstaller). But sadly the device name still there.

Answer (score 0):

Though you *could* do this directly from the Registry, the easiest way to disable or to uninstall USB devices, including cameras, is with the free utility from Nirsoft, [USBDeiew](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html). See the screenshot below:

[image: USBDeview]

It would be safer to just *disconnect or disable* the devices, rather than completely uninstall them, since you could back out those changes with just a click.

Comment: I can't seem find the name sir. Because it's directly from driver not from usb.